# get the previous element value

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a cart blade page on which products are shown with ajax add to cart action. I want to get the value of the input with name=quantity when a button is clicked. I want to do this with the jquery prev() function as there is right the code but it can't show any alert. Maybe it can't identify the class. So how can I do that? I have

```js
//Update Cart Items
$(document).on("click", ".btnItemUpdate", function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("qtyMinus")) {
    var quantity = $(this).prev().val();
    console.log(quantity);
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cart_quantity_button">
  <input class="cart_quantity_input" type="text" name="quantity" value="0" autocomplete="off" size="1" disabled>
  <button class="btnItemUpdate qtyMinus" type="button" data-cartid="{{$item['id']}}"> - </button>
  <button class="btnItemUpdate qtyPlus" type="button" data-cartid="{{$item['id']}}"> + </button>
</div>
```

Comment: working fine for me .

Comment: but i don't know why not for me?

Comment: It won't work for second button because the previous element is another button not the input you want

Comment: change `$(this).prev().val();` to `$(this).closest(".cart_quantity_button").find(".cart_quantity_input").val()` so that it will work for both button.

Comment: yes but even not working for minus btn too

Comment: Code shown works fine for the minus button. Something not shown is wrong

Comment: @Swati not working after changing the code.

Comment: @charlietfl I don't know why it's not working even everything is fine.

Comment: Have you put your jQuery code in a document.ready handler? Any errors in the console?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes, I have jQuery code no error in console. I have already work on different fields using ajax it works fine.

Comment: In that case I'm afraid we can't help, as given the code in the question, it works fine. You can even see this demonstrated in the snippet I edited in.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks and all of you for giving the valuable time.

Comment: why do you have `return false` there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
//Update Cart Items
$(document).on("click", ".btnItemUpdate", function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("qtyMinus")) {
    var quantity = $(this).prev().val();
    console.log(quantity);
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cart_quantity_button">
  <input class="cart_quantity_input" type="text" name="quantity" value="0" autocomplete="off" size="1" disabled>
  <button class="btnItemUpdate qtyMinus" type="button" data-cartid="{{$item['id']}}"> - </button>
  <button class="btnItemUpdate qtyPlus" type="button" data-cartid="{{$item['id']}}"> + </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).on("click", ".btnItemUpdate", function() {
    var quantity = parseInt($(this).closest('.cart_quantity_button').find('input[name="quantity"]').val());
    console.log(quantity);

    //add quantity by 1
    if ($(this).hasClass("qtyMinus")) {
        quantity--
        console.log(quantity);
    }

    //substract quantity by 1
    if ($(this).hasClass("qtyPlus")) {
        quantity++
        console.log(quantity);
    }
});
```

Above code will seek the closest div which has class `cart_quantity_button` from `.btnItemUpdate` and then will find an input which has `quantity` as its name , don't forget to parse quantity as integer using `parseInt()`